# Magento 1 admin panel and frontend on different servers

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there a guide on how to set up my front end and backend on separate servers? I am running magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

**one server will be frontend:**

- domain name www.example.com
- DNS ip pointed to `www`
- cache and sessions connected to redis on admin server
- /media/ folder mounted as NFS from admin server
- /var/log/ folder mounted as NFS from admin server

**second server admin:**

- domain name admin.example.com
- DNS ip pointed to subdomain `admin`
- cache and sessions configured in multiple redis instances
- /media/ folder configured as shared NFS storage
- /var/log/ folder configured as shared NFS storage
- files and code changes on admin server only
- rsync push from admin to frontend with delete option (delete non-existent files from frontend)
- exclude folders from rsync like media and some var, and other folder you create only for admin use.

good when you have local network between servers.